# List += Tuple vs List = List + Tuple

Tags: python, list, concatenation, tuples

Let's say I have these assignments:

```
points = []
point = (1, 2)
```

How come when I do this:

```
points += point
```

It works completely fine, and gives me points = [1, 2].
However, If I do something like:

```
points = points + point
```

It gives me a TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list.
Aren't these statements the same thing, though?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The difference, is that `list +=` is equivalent to `list.extend()`, which takes any iterable and extends the list, it works as a tuple is an iterable. (And extends the list in-place).

On the other hand, the second assigns a new list to `points`, and attempts to concatenate a list to a tuple, which isn't done as it's unclear what the expected results is (list or tuple?).