# Python list and tuple concatenation using plus equals

Tags: python, list, concatenation, tuples

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List += Tuple vs List = List + Tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332987/list-tuple-vs-list-list-tuple)

So I came across something rather odd and wanted to ask if anyone had any knowledge as to why this might be the case.

There exists some data in a list, and we want to add to that list all the values in tuple (as in `list.extend`)

```
>>> data = [0,1,2,3,4]
>>> data += (21,22,23) # all is well
>>> print(data)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 21, 22, 23]
```

also

```
>>> data = [0,1,2,3,4]
>>> data.extend( (21,22,23) ) # all is well
>>> print(data)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 21, 22, 23]
```

however

```
>>> data = [0,1,2,3,4]
>>> data = data + (21,22,23)
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list
```

These two seem to me the be the same operation, but the latter fails. What I take from this is that `+=` uses `extend` where as the latter doesn't, but is that.

Can someone explain the difference between these operations, and what's even more interesting why?

This appears to happen both in 2.7.3 and 3.2.1

Comment: Also, see the documentation for [`sequence` types](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange).  The docs specifically say that `s` and `t` are "sequences of the same type".  Note that `+=` isn't in the list of supported methods for a sequence -- As such, it's behavior is governed by the list type, not by the fact that lists are sequences.

Comment: didn't think to look for that title :)

Comment: I think you answered your own question. list.__iadd__(iterable) and list.extend(iterable) both get an iterable as an input, list.__add__(list) gets a list.