# Python: list operation when list is an element in tuple

Tags: list, python-2.7

I am using Python2.7.*, and trying a test of list operation when list is the element of a tuple.
but I found something I can not get myself understand:

```
>>> a = ([],)
>>> a[0] = a[0] + [1,2,3] 
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>  
 TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
>>> a
([],)

>>> b = ([], )
>>> b[0] += [1,2,3] 
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>  
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
>>> b
([1, 2, 3],)

>>> c = ([], )
>>> c[0].extend([1,2,3])
>>> 
>>> c
([1, 2, 3],)
```

I know that tuple is immutable and list is mutable, and I know that `list +=` is equivalent to `list.extend()` from [List += Tuple vs List = List + Tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332987/list-tuple-vs-list-list-tuple).
But now I am at sea that how to explain the code above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this code you are *assigning* to the first element, which is not possible in a tuple.

```
>>> a = ([],)
>>> a[0] = a[0] + [1,2,3]
```

Here, on the right hand side you are creating a new list from `a[0]+[1,2,3]` and then attempting to assign it back into `a[0]` which isn't legal.

In this code you are retrieving the first element of a tuple and then operating on that.

```
>>> c = ([], )
>>> c[0].extend([1,2,3])
```

Granted, its a small semantic difference, but it is that in the first you are attempting to reassign an element in a tuple. But lets look a little at whats happening behind the scenes:

Here we assign a list into `x` and observe how its id changes through different operations.

```
>>> x=[]
>>> id(x)
139987361764560
>>> id([])
139987361677112
>>> id(x+[1])
139987361829736
>>> x.append(1)
>>> x
[1]
>>> id(x)
139987361764560
```

Note that the id for `[]`, `x` and `x+[1]` are all different, but the id for `x` after we append a `1` is still the same. This reenforces the statement above that says that the statement `a[0] = a[0] + [1,2,3]` is creating a new list and then trying to assign it into the tuple.

But what of our tuple, well lets do some id checking again:

```
>>> id(y)
139987361830168
>>> id(y[0])
139987361677112
>>> id(y[1])
139987361723384
>>> y[1] = y[1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
>>> y[1].append(1)
>>> id(y[1])
139987361723384
>>> y
([], [1])
```

Again, we create a tuple, and can see that the tuple `y` and each of its elements have different ids. But note, we can't even assign the same list back into the same spot in the tuple. However, we can perform operations on that list as expected and see that the tuple changes.

**Regarding immutability:** The important thing to note here is that *the tuple doesn't change*, because the ids of the objects within the tuple don't change.

Comment: Thank you very much, what's a good answer it is. The sentence `the tuple doesn't change, because the ids of the objects within the tuple don't change` makes all clear!

Answer (score 0):

In Python,

```
a += b
```

is parsed as

```
a = a.__iadd__(b)
```

See reference [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__). It is not parsed as `a = a + b`, or `a = a.__add__(b)` if `a` has `__iadd__` method.

> These methods are called to implement the augmented arithmetic assignments (+=, -=, *=, @=, /=, //=, %=, **=, <<=, >>=, &=, ^=, |=). These methods should attempt to do the operation in-place (modifying self) and return the result (which could be, but does not have to be, self). If a specific method is not defined, the augmented assignment falls back to the normal methods. For instance, if x is an instance of a class with an **iadd**() method, x += y is equivalent to x = x.**iadd**(y) . Otherwise, x.**add**(y) and y.**radd**(x) are considered, as with the evaluation of x + y.

Let's see this example

```
class MyList(list):
    def __add__(self, x):
        print('add')
        return super().__add__(x)
    def __iadd__(self, x):
        print('iadd')
        return super().__iadd__(x)

a = (MyList(),)
a[0] += [1]
```

Running this in ipython

```
In [84]: class MyList(list):
    ...:     def __add__(self, x):
    ...:         print('add')
    ...:         return super().__add__(x)
    ...:     def __iadd__(self, x):
    ...:         print('iadd')
    ...:         return super().__iadd__(x)
    ...:
    ...: a = (MyList(),)
    ...: a[0] += [1]
iadd
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-84-d737d44c0c44> in <module>
      8
      9 a = (MyList(),)
---> 10 a[0] += [1]

TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

In [85]: a
Out[85]: ([1],)
```

Two interesting things to observe here

1. `iadd` is printed, thus `a[0] += [1]` is interpreted as `a[0] = a[0].__iadd__([1])` instead of `a[0] = a[0] + [1]`
2. Even though the assignment failed, `a` has been changed. this means `__iadd__()` has side effect

See this section from the official python documentation too. It explains exactly this situation/your question.

https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#faq-augmented-assignment-tuple-error