# Strange successfully concatenate tuple to list in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

check this:

```
>>>a = []
>>>a += 1,
>>>a
>>>[1]
>>>a += (2,)
>>>[1, 2]
```

Generally speaking，`1,` will perform a tuple:

```
>>>1,
>>>(1,)
```

and we already know that list can not be concatenate with tuple, but why `[] += 1,` execute successfully?

what does `+=` do and what happened to the interpreter in this situation?

Comment: are you sure about this 'list can not be concatenate with tuple' 
>>> a=[1,2]
>>> b
(1, 1, 2, 3)
>>> a+=b
>>> a
[1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3]

but I have taken an example and that's the output....

Comment: pure Python exception.`TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list`

Comment: Ohh Okk... why isn't gave me the exception?

Comment: you are doing `+=` but not `+`, and [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332987/list-tuple-vs-list-list-tuple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332987/list-tuple-vs-list-list-tuple) solved my problem, thank you so much.

Comment: Exactly... thank you....